# Replace the third comma on each line with newline

Tags: text-processing, csv

I have these long IDs which consist of four sections:

```
AKJHGFGUIKL,OIUYT,KJHBTYUI,98765434567
RTYUIKHGFGH,TYUJI,TGHYJKJKLJKL,6789876
ETRYTUUI,YTYUIL,UIOKJHGFGH,34567898766
```

I want to put the numbers in new line and remove the third comma.

```
AKJHGFGUIKL,OIUYT,KJHBTYUI
98765434567

RTYUIKHGFGH,TYUJI,TGHYJKJKLJKL
6789876

ETRYTUUI,YTYUIL,UIOKJHGFGH
34567898766
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Hello Simon Q. What have you tried so far?

Comment: @roaima I tried sed and awk but failed, I spent four hours on this!

Comment: @SimonQ, 4 hours, ouch!  Anyway, for next time please remember that it helps other learners (among whom are many good people also) to see the failed code.  It helps shows them what to avoid.

Answer (score 12):

Using GNU `sed`:

```
sed "s/,/\n/3; G" file

ETRYTUUI,YTYUIL,UIOKJHGFGH
34567898766
```

Explanation:

`sed` stands for stream editor..`sed` has the following syntax:

```
substitute/match(or pattern)/replacement/position file
```

In the above command, `s` substitute the third `,` by a new line `\n`.

`G` is to append a new line to the contents of the pattern space and then append the contents of the hold space to the pattern space.

Answer (score 6):

```
awk -F, -vOFS=, '{print $1,$2,$3; print $4; print ""}' file
```

will produce your desired output

Answer (score 4):

A few Perl approaches:

```
$ perl -pe 's/,([^,]+)$/\n$1\n/' file
AKJHGFGUIKL,OIUYT,KJHBTYUI
98765434567

RTYUIKHGFGH,TYUJI,TGHYJKJKLJKL
6789876

ETRYTUUI,YTYUIL,UIOKJHGFGH
34567898766
```

The `-p` means "read the input file line by line and print each line after applying the script given by `-e` to it". The `s/foo/bar/` is the substitution operator which will replace `foo` with `bar`. Here, we are matching a comma followed by one or more non-comma characters (`[^,]+`) until the end of the line (`$`). The parentheses  around the `([^,]+)` will "capture" whatever is matched so we can refer to it as `$1` on the right hand side of the operator. Therefore, this will replace the text after the last comma with a newline, then the matched text and then another newline.

If you can't be sure the third comma is the last one, you can do:

```
perl -pe 's/([^,]+,){3}\K(.+)/\n$2\n/' file
```

or

```
perl -pe 's/(.+?,.+?,.+?),(.+)/$1\n$2\n/' file
```

And here are some more, just for fun:

```
perl -pe 's/([^,]+,){3}\K(.+)/\n$2\n/' file
perl -F, -pe '$k=pop(@F); $_=join(",", @F)."\n$k\n"' file
perl -F, -le 'print join ",", @F[0..2],"\n@F[3..$#F]\n"' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternative less succinct `sed` code:

```
sed 's/,\([^,]*\)/\n\1\n/3' file
```

...which can be used if the *hold buffer* were needed for some other purpose, (supposing some additional requirement). If you need portable code (the above is `gnu sed` syntax) use literal newlines in the RHS:

```
sed 's/,\([^,]*\)/\
\1\
/3' file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F, '{print $1, $2, $3,"\n"$4}'
```

Comment: You'd need to set `OFS=,` as well in order to preserve the other delimiters

Comment: @steeldriver but it will not remove the third comma as requested?

Comment: ... then change the last part to a simple concatenation `$3 "\n" $4`

Comment: This removes all commas, replacing them with spaces and doesn't add the extra newline between records. Please make sure your output is the same as the desired output shown in the question.

Answer (score 0):

A more portable sed solution:

```
<infile sed -E 'G;s/(.*),(.*)(\n)/\1\3\2\3/'
```

Awk solution(s):

```
<infile  awk -F, '{printf("%s,%s,%s\n%s\n\n",$1,$2,$3,$4)}'
<infile gawk     '{match($0,/(.*),(.*)/,a);print(a[1]"\n"a[2]"\n")}'
```